# i want to read an integer from user input?

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int? tec = null;


        int avetec = tec ?? 0 ;

        Console.Write("Avalaple tec = {0}", avetec);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

i want to read an integer from user input while using the Null coalescing operator

Comment: Why would you use `Null coalescing operator` for that task?

Comment: There is no need to use the Null Coalescing operator here. Use Console.ReadLine nor ReadKey then you have a string that you can try to convert to an integer with Int32.TryParse and get back zero if it is not a valid integer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

int? tec = null;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
    tec = int.Parse(input);
}

int avetec = tec ?? 0;
```

It checks if the input in empty. If so, it uses the default value specified by you. Otherwise it will parse the input to an integer.

---

If you want to handle cases where the input might be invalid, use `int.TryParse`, as in this sample:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
    int tecIntermediate;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out tecIntermediate))
    {
        tec = tecIntermediate;
    }
    else
    {
        // handle the invalid output, you can default or notify the user.
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the input contains alphabetical characters? Also this doesn't utilise the `??` operator, I don't think this answers OP's question.

Comment: I guess you know the answer: it will throw an exception as expected. If you want to avoid that use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: The first if statement in your second code snippet is somewhat redundant.

Comment: Not if the default is something else than 0.

Comment: Int32.TryParse handles also null values (with Console.ReadLine we could get a null output if you type CTRL+Z then Enter)

Comment: I don't have anything to test it but I'm pretty sure you cant pass `Nullable<T>` to the `int.TryParse` method, you will have to create additional variable.

Comment: @Steve but it will return `0`, not `null`, which might care when there is another default value than `0`.